# Linked CSS stylesheet will not work unless manually set to UTF-8 every time something is changed in VSCode

Tags: html, css

I need to program a website for a school project and am pretty new to html and CSS. I'm using VS Code and wanted to link a simple CSS stylesheet to a html file and used `<link  rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">`. This is consistent with things I found on the internet. Now VSC even had the file as an autofill option so it obviously knows it is there. The CSS file is in the same folder as the html file. But it just wouldn't do anything.

First I simply opened CSS as an administrator but no luck. So I googled and found another thread on here that said to open the CSS file in notepad++ and manually set the encoding to UTF-8 which to my joy worked as the background was indeed black as I wanted it but as soon as I tried changing it back to white it just didn't do anything again. Another round of manually setting the encoding to UTF-8(mind you notepad++ already recognized it as encoded in UTF-8) and on the next startup of vsc it worked changing the background to white but after trying to change it back again it didn't do anything. And its not the browser of the preview plugin I'm using either as I've tried Chrome as well. This is the html and CSS code but there shouldn't be any things interfering as it is just the minimal amount of code needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Tauchen.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test123</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you have Visual Studio Code configured to save in an encoding other than UTF-8? I don't know VS Code, but if you search the settings for "encoding" or "charset" you might find that it's defaulting to some ancient Windows character encoding (when you save changes in VS Code), which might break things when the web browser tries to open it using UTF-8 encoding.